# Any alternatives to Google's Generic DAO?

Tags: java, hibernate, genericdao

For some time, I was using [Google's Generic DAO](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.genericdao/dao-hibernate) paired with Hibernate. 
But now [Google's Generic DAO](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.genericdao/dao-hibernate) no longer developed & I decided to find an alternative.
Advise an alternative, pls! Except Spring.

Comment: I think you need to post this question in superuser.com.. You will get better solution.

Comment: If you are using Spring then http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/. If you are using CDI then https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/data.html. Otherwise not sure.

Comment: Isn't the EntityManager in JPA kind of like a generic DAO?